# LOAD DATA INFILE not working with CSV containing encoded JSON value in field data

Tags: php, mysql, json, csv, load-data-infile

I have millions of records to insert in mysql table. To quickly migrate data into table I tried to use LOAD DATA INFILE concept.

Below is the format of the data in CSV file (some of the fields having JSON data).

```
"1299","1420070400000","35520","1420070400000","0","0","0","2","null","{""types"": [3]}","{""types"": [2]}","{""type"": 0, ""color"": 0, ""types"": [1], ""colors"": [2]}","null","null","null","null","{""type"": 0, ""types"": [], ""sexDrive"": 0, ""sexDrives"": [1]}","null","{""results"": [2]}","{""types"": [3]}","null","null","null","{""types"": [5]}","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","2020-01-30 11:48:07","2020-01-30 11:48:07"

"1300","1420070400000","48219","1420070400000","0","0","0","2","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","2020-01-30 11:48:07","2020-01-30 11:48:07"

"1301","1420070400000","34938","1420070400000","0","0","0","2","null","null","null","{""type"": 0, ""color"": 0, ""types"": [1], ""colors"": [3]}","null","null","{""types"": [2]}","{""pain"": 0, ""pains"": [2], ""otherPains"": [3, 4, 5, 6], ""breastSymptom"": false, ""breastSymptoms"": [1]}","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","2020-01-30 11:48:07","2020-01-30 11:48:07"
```

When I tried to execute the code it shows error as below -

**SQLSTATE[22032]: <>: 3140 Invalid JSON text: "Missing a comma or '}' after an object member." at position 42 in value for column 'user_day_record.notesObj'**

Basically, when I try to execute same command without JSON values in CSV it works perfectly. But with JSON data (in some fields) in file it gives error.

Here is the command -

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$file' INTO TABLE user_day_record CHARACTER SET UTF8 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ', ' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Can anyone help me to execute the command successfully with json values in fields in CSV file?

**Update -**

Here is the structure of the `user_day_record`table -

[image: user_day_record_table]

Comment: Can you show the structure of the `user_day_record` table and some rows of the table (`user_day_record`) when you insert without the JSON values?. Please, edit the question and add the information.

Comment: @wchiquito, I put the table structure screenshot in the update. Please have a look.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution to load a CSV file which contains the JSON object.
Below are extra options we have to use to import

fields terminated by ',' 
   optionally enclosed by '\"'
   escaped by '\' 
   escaped by '\"' 
   lines terminated by '\n'

````
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: user_day_record
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `user_day_record` (
  `dayRecordld` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id` varchar(191) NOT NULL,
  `userld` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `daylnMillis` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `periodStatusActive` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ignoreB8T` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `isOCOff` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `version` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bbt` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `cervicalMucusObj` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `cervicalPositionObj` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `spotting` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `periodStrength` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `temperaturelnterferenceObj` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `hygieneProductsObj` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `pain` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `intercourse` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `ovulationTestObj` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `pregnancyTestObj` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `illnessObj` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `medicationObj` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `notesObj` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `sleep` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `emotionsObj` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `activitiesObj` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `oralContraceptives` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `digestion` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `pExams` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `pMyBaby` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `pUltrasound` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `pVitamin` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `pWeight` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dayRecordld`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> load data local infile '/var/root/temp_Data.csv' into table user_day_record fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '\"'  escaped by '\\' escaped by '\"' lines terminated by '\n';
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql>
mysql> select * from user_day_record\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               dayRecordld: 1299
                        id: 1420070400000
                    userld: 35520
               daylnMillis: 1420070400000
        periodStatusActive: 0
                 ignoreB8T: 0
                   isOCOff: 0
                   version: 2
                       bbt: null
          cervicalMucusObj: {"types": [3]}
       cervicalPositionObj: {"types": [2]}
                  spotting: {"type": 0, "color": 0, "types": [1], "colors": [2]}
            periodStrength: null
temperaturelnterferenceObj: null
        hygieneProductsObj: null
                      pain: null
               intercourse: {"type": 0, "types": [], "sexDrive": 0, "sexDrives": [1]}
          ovulationTestObj: null
          pregnancyTestObj: {"results": [2]}
                illnessObj: {"types": [3]}
             medicationObj: null
                  notesObj: null
                     sleep: null
               emotionsObj: {"types": [5]}
             activitiesObj: null
        oralContraceptives: null
                 digestion: null
                    pExams: null
                   pMyBaby: null
               pUltrasound: null
                  pVitamin: null
                   pWeight: null
                created_at: 2020-01-30 11:48:07
                updated_at: 2020-01-30 11:48:07
*************************** 2. row ***************************
               dayRecordld: 1300
                        id: 1420070400000
                    userld: 48219
               daylnMillis: 1420070400000
        periodStatusActive: 0
                 ignoreB8T: 0
                   isOCOff: 0
                   version: 2
                       bbt: null
          cervicalMucusObj: null
       cervicalPositionObj: null
                  spotting: null
            periodStrength: null
temperaturelnterferenceObj: null
        hygieneProductsObj: null
                      pain: null
               intercourse: null
          ovulationTestObj: null
          pregnancyTestObj: null
                illnessObj: null
             medicationObj: null
                  notesObj: null
                     sleep: null
               emotionsObj: null
             activitiesObj: null
        oralContraceptives: null
                 digestion: null
                    pExams: null
                   pMyBaby: null
               pUltrasound: null
                  pVitamin: null
                   pWeight: null
                created_at: 2020-01-30 11:48:07
                updated_at: 2020-01-30 11:48:07
*************************** 3. row ***************************
               dayRecordld: 1301
                        id: 1420070400000
                    userld: 34938
               daylnMillis: 1420070400000
        periodStatusActive: 0
                 ignoreB8T: 0
                   isOCOff: 0
                   version: 2
                       bbt: null
          cervicalMucusObj: null
       cervicalPositionObj: null
                  spotting: {"type": 0, "color": 0, "types": [1], "colors": [3]}
            periodStrength: null
temperaturelnterferenceObj: null
        hygieneProductsObj: {"types": [2]}
                      pain: {"pain": 0, "pains": [2], "otherPains": [3, 4, 5, 6], "breastSymptom": false, "breastSymptoms": [1]}
               intercourse: null
          ovulationTestObj: null
          pregnancyTestObj: null
                illnessObj: null
             medicationObj: null
                  notesObj: null
                     sleep: null
               emotionsObj: null
             activitiesObj: null
        oralContraceptives: null
                 digestion: null
                    pExams: null
                   pMyBaby: null
               pUltrasound: null
                  pVitamin: null
                   pWeight: null
                created_at: 2020-01-30 11:48:07
                updated_at: 2020-01-30 11:48:07
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>```
````

Comment: escaped by '\'  above SHOULD BE: escaped by '\\' or it messes up your query.